# Wildfly deploy error, ModuleLoadError {lombok, apache.commons}

Tags: java, docker, wildfly, lombok, apache-commons

I'm running a docker image of Wildfly, it seems to be starting properly since no errors are showing until it starts deploying an ear that uses apache log4j, commons and lombok. I don't know why, but I expected them to be included in the ear or war files; since they were included in the pom dependencies.

I've been able to fix it by include the missing jars inside the `modules\system\layers\base` wildfly folder; But as far as I know it shouldn't be necessary since I want to use the docker files that you can read below.

When it starts deploying it fails and throws this error:

```
wildfly  | 20:39:46,793 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0001: /content/SIC.ear/org.co.oengin-SIC-WEB-3.1.war/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml in subdeployment ignored. jboss-deployment-structure.xml is only parsed for top level deployments.
wildfly  | 20:39:46,800 INFO  [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYPOJO0001: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions).
wildfly  | 20:39:46,807 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for Portal-PersistenceUnit
wildfly  | 20:39:46,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for SIC-PersistenceUnit
wildfly  | 20:39:46,965 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'SIC.ear#Portal-PersistenceUnit'
wildfly  | 20:39:46,966 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
wildfly  |      name: Portal-PersistenceUnit
wildfly  |      ...]
wildfly  | 20:39:46,966 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'SIC.ear/org.co.oengin-SIC-Persistence-3.1.jar#SIC-PersistenceUnit'
wildfly  | 20:39:46,967 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
wildfly  |      name: SIC-PersistenceUnit
wildfly  |      ...]
wildfly  | 20:39:46,967 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment SIC.ear
wildfly  | 20:39:47,027 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment org.co.oengin-SIC-EPOS-INTEGRATION-3.1.jar
wildfly  | 20:39:47,032 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failed to define class org.co.oengin.utils.web.jsf.JSFBaseBean in Module "ingeneo.utils.fyl-web" from local module loader @4470fbd6 (finder: local module finder @15d49048 (roots: /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules,/opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base)): org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.lombok
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1417)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1295)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPaths(Module.java:1583)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1606)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:726)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1096)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1096)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.jsf@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.deploy(JSFComponentProcessor.java:105)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
wildfly  |
wildfly  | 20:39:47,032 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failed to define class org.co.oengin.cim.web.util.JSFBaseBeanSIC in Module "deployment.SIC.ear.org.co.oengin-SIC-WEB-3.1.war" from Service Module Loader: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.lombok
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1417)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1295)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPaths(Module.java:1583)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1606)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:726)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1096)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1096)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.jsf@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.deploy(JSFComponentProcessor.java:105)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
wildfly  |
wildfly  | 20:39:47,033 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failed to define class org.co.oengin.cim.web.controller.DistributorTreeController in Module "deployment.SIC.ear.org.co.oengin-SIC-WEB-3.1.war" from Service Module Loader: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.lombok
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1417)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1295)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPaths(Module.java:1583)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1606)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:726)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1096)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1096)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.jsf@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.deploy(JSFComponentProcessor.java:105)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
wildfly  |
wildfly  | 20:39:47,033 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."SIC.ear"."org.co.oengin-SIC-WEB-3.1.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."SIC.ear"."org.co.oengin-SIC-WEB-3.1.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "org.co.oengin-SIC-WEB-3.1.war" of deployment "SIC.ear"
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
wildfly  |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
wildfly  | Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.lombok
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1417)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.jsf@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.deploy(JSFComponentProcessor.java:105)
wildfly  |      at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
wildfly  |      ... 8 more
```

Using the following files:

**pom.xml of war**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.co.oengin</groupId>
        <artifactId>Portal</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Portal-Web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Portal-Web</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.co.oengin</groupId>
            <artifactId>Portal-Business</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk20</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>${taglibs-standard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:16.0.0.Final
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#70365 --silent
ADD wildfly/modules/postgres /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/postgresql/main

ADD wildfly/modules/oracle /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/oracle/main

ADD wildfly/modules/org /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org

COPY wildfly/standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration # to add the datasources
COPY wildfly/ejb.properties /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration
EXPOSE 8080 9990
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  wildfly:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: wildfly
    restart: always     
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9990:9990"
    volumes:
      - ./wildfly_deployment_scanner:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
    entrypoint: ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]`
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace further up in the logs?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins just updated the logs

Comment: That definitely looks strange. I would try maybe ensuring lombok doesn't end up in your WAR. As far as I know it's not needed at runtime.